# Replicating this Live Time core functionality

Tags: javascript, php, date, time

I'm trying to develop a simple `LiveDateTime` object that's reliable, accurate and somewhat independent of the client system date as far as the updating of the time goes.

I've tried several solutions:

- Taking the server date and the time difference with the client system date to calculate the elapsed time and update the time accordingly every 150ms.
- Taking the client system UTC date and increase it with a second every 1000ms with `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`.  Also tried it with a self-correcting delay loop.
- Some similar variants of the above.

All of the above didn't meet the requirements, either because if the client system date was changed it would set the live time off as well, or just the delay of the loop was inaccurate and drifting off over time.

So, I decided to just go online and search for some popular websites that have what I want already implemented and working. I stumbled upon this [Greenwich Mean Time](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time/scripts/clock-8/runner.php?tz=europe_paris) example that's reliable, accurate and somewhat independent of the client system. If I change the date of my system, the date that they display is unaffected.

Upon inspecting their code I found it hard trying to understand what they are doing that I could replicate, because either their code is badly written or I'm not that advanced enough to understand it.

I do know that they use AJAX calls (`request.js`) to the server for something (maybe the server time). And that they're using a `setInterval(func, 150)` and a whole bunch of other presentational methods of which I think aren't the core of the live time's functionality.

Anyone who could help me figuring out the core of the functionality of their accurate live time? If I can figure that out, from there it would be easy for me to replicate.

Comment: If only there was some way to inspect the rendered HTML and see the used javascripts of a website. If it would be possible to see requests a website makes that would be even more awesome. If only...

Comment: The thing even has comments all over the code and is just a couple of lines long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is combined with a server-side language to get the server time. The time is directly written into the JS by PHP, in this line for example:

```
var ServerDSTCheck = new Date(parseFloat(1426849548940.7)).getTime();
```

That float `1426849548940.7` comes from the server, and that's why it's not affected by the client machine time. The AJAX call returns the same thing in intervals to maintain the server time, so it can't be messed up on the client and to avoid the client lag.

That's the base of what you need. The rest of the code is about daylight savings, timezone compensation and presentational stuff.

Comment: So they are in fact actually requesting the server for the timestamp every 150ms?

Comment: No, it's a bit longer: this part `(chgChkInt < chgChk) || ((chgChkInt-chgChk) > 1000) || (chgChkInt == chgChk)` tries to call it about every second. The 150ms is for the client only, but the server is called only after those checks. It's not called all the time, maybe just until they figure out the client lag. I get between 4 and 8 calls.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Cause when I disconnect from the Internet, the time also still works perfectly.

Comment: It should fail if you change your machine time/settings.

Comment: Indeed it does. I think I'm starting to figure it out. `(chgChkInt < chgChk) || ((chgChkInt-chgChk) > 1000) || (chgChkInt == chgChk)`: This checks if the client time has been changed back into the past compared to the server time, or if the client time difference with the server's is bigger then 1 second, or if it's unchanged, **then** it queries the server for the timestamp. Hence the reason it doesn't work when disconnected from the Internet and changing the time further in the future or back into the past, because it will try to get the reliable timestamp directly from the server. Correct?

Comment: Exactly, it also explains the randomness of the calls when you're online - it fires just when needed.

Comment: I almost got it, but last thing I can't figure out is how the time is actually increasing?

Comment: This line does it: `writer("offset",clockInstance.apOffsetTime,"ap_offset_value");`. Look inside files calc.js and writer.js to get a better picture of what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want independent clock in JS, right? It's pretty simple:

1. Make an ajax request to your server, while the script is loaded by the user, to get current time (UNIX).
2. Set interval for example 1 sec, and just increment your time, that you get in pt 1, for the interval you choose.

When user change his time on local machine it wouldn't affect the script, also refreshing script would again load time from your server.

Comment: But relying on the interval time to increase the time by a second is not accurate since it drifts off after awhile.

Comment: Yes, that's why they're calling that `x.php` file to fetch the server time constantly - I've explained it in my answer.

Comment: @KidDiamond: Increasing a counter in a timeout loop will become inaccurate – but the internal time won’t. So use `Date` objects, and add/subtract your offset to/from them. If you are worried about someone changing their client time – then do check with the server to get the current offset every x seconds or so.

Answer (score 1):

Since js timers are extremely unreliable by default I'd say you must use two parallel intervals.

One, which will correct the frontend's time drift against server time and other which will fill in the blanks on the frontend (to not strain the server and user's connection).

```
var time = Date.now(); // Or initial server time
var oldTime = Date.now();
var newTime = oldTime;

var feInterval = setInterval( function() {
    // Incrementing "time" by whatever frontend difference, aka Delta time
    time += ( newTime = Date.now() ) - oldTime;
    oldTime = newTime;
 }, 40 );

var beInterval = setInterval( function() { 
    // Fetch server UTC milliseconds and overwrite "time".
    // Above interval will just use that as a new base time.
    var serverTime = Math.random() * 10000000000; //use Ajax to get server time.
    time = serverTime;
 }, 10000 );

setInterval( function() {
    // Do something with "time"
    // This interval is just for demo, you don't need it in general - use your own "time" consumer.
    console.log( 'Fairly correct time (random each 10 seconds):', new Date ( time ).toString() );
}, 40 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is someone else trying solve the same problem,

check out below page,

[show server time including timezone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29285295/3923450)