# show server time including timezone offset

Tags: javascript, php, time

i have some difficulties showing the actual time of the server using php and js.
on the server-side i have following php code:

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

on the client-side if have the following js code that changes the content of a div to display the current time:

```
flag = true;
timer = '';


function clock()
{
        if ( flag ) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "backend/time_backend.php?action=serverTime", false);
            xmlhttp.send();

            var stamp = xmlhttp.responseText;


            timer = stamp*1000;
        }
        var d = new Date(timer);

        var hours = d.getHours();
        var minutes = d.getMinutes();
        var seconds = d.getSeconds();

        //hours = hours % 12;
        //hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour ’0' should be ’12'
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0'+seconds : seconds;
        var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML= strTime ;

        flag = false;
        timer = timer + 1000;
}

window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(clock, 1000);
};
```

this works as long as the timezone of the server and mine are the same. but as soon as i change the timezone on the server, it doesn't work anymore. it still will show my local client time although the bash command `date` on the server shows the time in the right offset.

how do i fix this? i really need to show the server-local time.

Comment: Does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6621656/989920
I don't think the problem is with the JS, as this is only converting the timestamp provided by your server. The issue is likely to be with the code providing the timestamp in `time_backend.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending in unix timestamp from PHP
must be probably using

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```

if you want to use the string for creating date object using JS.

Your JS code should be

```
function clock()
{
    if ( flag ) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "backend/time_backend.php?action=serverTime", false);
        xmlhttp.send();

        var stamp = xmlhttp.responseText;

        var timer = new Date(stamp);
    }
    var d = new Date(timer);

    var hours = d.getHours();
    var minutes = d.getMinutes();
    var seconds = d.getSeconds();

    //hours = hours % 12;
    //hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour ’0' should be ’12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0'+seconds : seconds;
    var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML= strTime ;

    flag = false;
    timer = new Date(timer.getTime() + 1000);
}
```

Comment: You dont need to do "timer = stamp*1000;" any more as the time comes in the expected format.

Comment: But this assumes time is requested from the server every second.

Comment: Had to make few more updates to your code - see if the above version work.
Btw I am assuming that your ajax call has a 200 response, with the date value coming in response in format '2015-03-26 18:02:15'
Make sure to check that in your browser console.

Comment: this worked! yay! i think, the thing that made this one work is the fact, that you're not appending the UTC offset to the datetime-string like the ISO 8601 format from @pixeleet does. therefore, the client can't calculate the date to local time... that's at least my guess ;)  
thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ISO 8601 formatted date.

```
$date = date("c", time());
```

Will give you one.

> ISO 8601 Data elements and interchange formats – Information
>   interchange – Representation of dates and times is an international
>   standard covering the exchange of date and time-related data. It was
>   issued by the International Organization for Standardization (ISO) and
>   was first published in 1988. The purpose of this standard is to
>   provide an unambiguous and well-defined method of representing dates
>   and times, so as to avoid misinterpretation of numeric representations
>   of dates and times, **particularly when data are transferred between
>   countries with different conventions for writing numeric dates and
>   times.**

You could then do [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) in which will return a timestamp ;) then proceed as if you received a timestamp.

Comment: sadly, js still shows the client-local time. `console.log(stamp)` printed `2015-03-26T20:44:16+02:00` (bucharest timezone) and the browser showed me `19:44:16` (which is my local time, berlin timezone).

Comment: Okay, I see your problem :) painfully enough, javascript will always try and convert it to your local time. So what you could do to ease your pain. 

Because doing a `new Date(stamp)` directly also results in conversion to your local timezone. That you keep track of the offset compared to your timezone. You'll have to then add or subtract that from the timestamp :(

If I get it and you're trying to display the time that's on the server and not on the client. Right? :)

Comment: yes, you're right. defining the datetime-format without providing the offset works though. see jacob's answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

`Date::getTimestamp` always returns the [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Unix timestamp does not store time zone information.

Solution is to build the JavaScript Date object from the date information given by the server.

**Note:** The time will not go out of sync when server or the client changes time zones (i.e. DST). If avoiding requests to backend a more accurate solution would be to use a time zone library in JavaScript (e.g. [timezone.js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js)).

PHP:

```
$date = new DateTime;

echo json_encode(array(
    'year' => (int) $date->format('Y'),
    'month' => (int) $date->format('m'),
    'day' => (int) $date->format('j'),
    'hours' => (int) $date->format('H'),
    'minutes' => (int) $date->format('i'),
    'seconds' => (int) $date->format('s'),
));
```

JavaScript:

```
var date = null;

function updateTime() {
    if (!date) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "backend/time_backend.php?action=serverTime", false);
        xmlhttp.send();

        var j = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        date = new Date(
            j['year'], j['month'],
            j['day'], j['hours'],
            j['minutes'], j['seconds']
        );

        return;
    }

    // Increment time by 1 second
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + 1000);
}

function clock() {
    updateTime();

    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();

    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour ’0' should be ’12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0'+seconds : seconds;
    var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = strTime;
}

window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(clock, 1000);
};
```